# Fast vector addition of multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-itertools

I need to add up multiple columns of large DataFrames in a loop. It's taking very long. The bottleneck is in creating copies of the DataFrame.

Here is a simplified code sample of what I am trying to do:

```
import itertools as it

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def sum_combo_ranks(df, combos: list[str]) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Returns the sum of the composite ranks for each combination of columns..

    Returns:
        DataFrame
            Each column contains a single system
            Each row is a date/ticker
            Each cell contains the aggregated rank for that stock on that date.
    """

    # Each DataFrame in lst is the sum of a single combination of selected columns;
    # This step is a bottleneck.
    # 2.9s
    lst = [df[x] for x in combos]

    # For each subset, add each row across.
    # 2.1s
    sums = [x.sum(axis=1)
            for x in lst]

    # Join the list of df's into a single DataFrame.
    # 0.3s
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(sums)

    return new_df



# Sample DataFrame. In real life it has real numbers.
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros([6000, 100]))       

# Generate a list of multiple combinations of 98 column numbers out of 100.
combos = list(list(x) for x in it.combinations(range(100), 98))[:1000]  

result = sum_combo_ranks(df, combos)
```

The biggest chunk of time is spent making numerous copies of the relevant columns. There should be a way to add up the relevant columns by reference.

Is this possible? How can we speed up this operation?

Comment: Can you explain, _in words_, what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark: I am not sure I understand your question. I am trying to add up `axis=1` for multiple subsets of a DataFrame.

Comment: It's part of a ML type algo to look for a pattern in the best factors to use for ranking stocks.

Comment: I have over a hundred different columns. Ideally, if it would be possible, I would test the entire [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of column combinations. For each subset I would add all columns along axis=1 and see how well it predicts stock returns.

Comment: Can you explain what your code snippet does, in English?

Comment: Use the numpy array underlying the dataframe would be faster generally speaking probably not enough for doing the power set

Comment: @Ben.T: Yes. I tried that too, but it is still pretty slow. I am looking for a way to sum up specific rows in a numpy array without making a new copy of the array subset.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of columns that you are discarding is >> than number of columns that you are selecting to sum, you could seep up your code using:

```
import itertools as it

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros([6000, 100]))       # Sample DataFrame. In real life it has real numbers.
combos = list(list(x) for x in it.combinations(range(100), 98))[:1000]# List multiple combinations.
combos2 = list(list(x) for x in it.combinations(range(100), 2))[:1000]# List multiple combinations

%%timeit
new_df = pd.DataFrame([df[x].sum(axis=1) for x in combos])   
#1.6 s ± 16.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%%timeit
s = df.sum(axis=1)
new_df = pd.DataFrame([s.sub(df[x].sum(axis=1)) for x in combos2])
#653 ms ± 3.04 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

But you should post more information about your problem

Comment: That's a fine optimization. I use it in some of my algo's. What I am looking for is a more general solution that works faster.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost 6x as fast:

```
def sum_combo_ranks2(df: pd.DataFrame, combos: list[str]) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Returns the sum of the composite ranks for each combination of columns.

    Returns:
        DataFrame
            Each column contains a single system
            Each row is a date/ticker
            Each cell contains the aggregated rank for that stock on that date.
    """
    
    # Each df is a copy of the original but with the unwanted columns set to 0.
    # 0.4s!
    all_cols = list(range(100))
    df_lst = [df[:]
              for _ in range(len(combos))]  # Much faster than [df[x] for x in combos]
    
    # Set value of unwanted columns in each df to 0.  
    for item, combo in zip(df_lst, combos):
        zero_cols = [x for x in all_cols
                     if x not in combo]
        item.iloc[:, zero_cols] = 0.0

    # Create a list of 1D totals for each combination of columns.
    sums = [np.sum(x.to_numpy(), axis=1)
            for x in df_lst]    # 0.37 s

    # Join the list of df's into a single DataFrame.
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(np.stack(sums, axis=1))   # 0.7s

    return new_df
```

Notes on the algorithm:

1. Creating full size copies of the original `DataFrame` and then setting unwanted columns to 0 is much faster than creating multiple subsets of the original `DataFrame`.
2. `np.sum(df.to_numpy())` is much faster than `df.sum()`.

Comment: This code has a bug. `df[:]` creates a view; not a copy.